# How can i write the formula 'Advance Distance = Radius * (Tan(Delta/2))' as a react native function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Input two variables to get third (all decimals rounded to tenths)

i. Degrees of Course Change (aka Delta)

ii. Radius (nautical miles)

iii. Advance distance (nautical miles)

b. Base formula: Advance Distance = Radius * (Tan(Delta/2))

i. AKA: Advance distance equals the radius times the tangent of half of the
angle of the course change

c. Examples (user inputs highlighted yellow, app calculated answer highlighted
green):

i. Delta (deg): 60; Radius (nm): 1.5; Advance (nm): 0.87

1. Advance (nm) = (1.5) * (Tan(60/2))

ii. Delta (deg): 140; Radius (nm): 1.0; Advance (nm): 2.75

1. Advance (nm) = (1.0) * (Tan(140/2))

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TextInput, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

class AdvanceForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            advance: 0,
            input: '',
            radius: '',
            delta: '',
            calc: 0
        };
        this.onButtonPressed = this.onButtonPressed.bind(this);
        this.calcAdvance = this.calcAdvance.bind(this);
        this.storeData = this.storeData.bind(this);
    }


  onButtonPressed = function() { this.setState({ advance:this.state.radius })}
  _handleTextChange = radius => { this.setState({ radius }); 
  };
  _handleTextChange2 = delta => { this.setState({ delta }); 
  };


  calcAdvance = async function() {
  
    var x = parseFloat(this.state.radius);
    var y = parseFloat(this.state.delta);
    var calc = (x) * (Math.tan((Math.tan(y / 2))));
    this.setState({ advance: calc})
    this.storeData(await this.state.advance)
    return;
  }

   
  
  //save the input
 storeData = async () => {
    let advance = this.state.advance;
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@advance', advance.toString())
    console.log('Stored Advance: ' + advance)
    return;
}
        

   render() {
    const {advance} = this.state;
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Advance Distance:  { advance.toFixed(2) } (nm)
        </Text>

        <Text style={styles.text}> Radius (nm): </Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.radius}
          keyboardType = 'numeric'
          onChangeText={this._handleTextChange}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <Text style={styles.text}> Delta (deg): </Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.delta}
          keyboardType = 'numeric'
          onChangeText={this._handleTextChange2}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.calcAdvance.bind(this)} 
          style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Calculate</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>

      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      
    );
  }

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 10,
    
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    width: 300,
    height: 35,
    color: 'white'
  },
  button: {
    padding: 18,
    margin: 16,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 50, 
    width: 300
  },
  buttonText:{
    color: 'white'
  }
});

export default AdvanceForm;
```

Comment: React (native) is largely irrelevant here, this is JavaScript math. Please describe what specific issue you're trying to solve. Are you getting errors? Does something not work as expected? Note that setting state is async and you cannot await it, you have to use `componentDidUpdate` to react to state changes

Comment: i. Delta (deg): 60; Radius (nm): 1.5; Advance (nm): 0.87

Advance (nm) = (1.5) * (Tan(60/2))

Comment: this is returning the wrong value when i input the radius and delta

Comment: Trigonometric functions use Radians values, not Degree values. Convert to Radians first.